# How to create a polygon on a texture libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, polygon

I want to create a polygon by cutting the transparent area from a texture. 
I wrote a program which detects collision between 2 objects. 
But the collision is detected before they are in collision. 
That's how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifecj.jpg

This is the code: https://hastebin.com/bebusadiku.java
I thought to cut the texture and create a polygon based on the cutted texture and then detect the collision using an Intersector method but I have no idea how to specify the vertexes of the polygon.

I tried to follow this but there's no explain how to detect the vertexes :
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114228/how-to-detect-collision-only-in-non-transparent-texture

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this polygonal shape editor](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/physics-body-editor/) to create more complex shapes for checking collisions. I believe with Box2D it works out of the "box" but Box2D takes a lot of space and that is unnecessary if you don't use the actual physics. However, this tool generates `JSON` formatted polygonal coordinates and it's not that hard to deserialize that back into [Polygon](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Polygon.html) objects and do collision with the [Intersector implementation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html). So in steps you:

- Create a shape for your images using the [shape editor tool](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/physics-body-editor/).
- Export that to JSON with the tool.
- Deserialize that data into a LibGDX `Polygon`
- Move, scale and attach it properly to your image so it's synchronized.
- First check collision on a basic rectangle vs rectangle.
- If there is a basic collision do a more detailed collision detection with `Intersector`.

The tool exports a lot of redundant data, if you get yourself familiar with the format it exports you can get rid of all data except the polygon/vertices data.

Comment: I thought to do this but I want to create an universal class which cuts the images in the constructor, so I need an algorithm or a script for Physics Body Editor. But the problem with the script is when I port my game on android it won't work. I've an idea to cut the image pixel by pixel but my implementation could be very inefficient and lag my game. But I've no idea if Texture class has methods which recognize the pixel color and allow to operate on pixels. And if it works I could try to find the extreme points on a texture and create a polygon based on this points.

Comment: Yes, create a pixmap for the texture. And do some Bressingham line of sight technique along the edges to find your vertices. Then create a delaunai triangle from it to end up with only concave polygons.

Comment: Sorry for my english but what does it mean Bressingham line and delaunai?By the way, are there any algorithms which could help me or must I  implement everything from zero?

Comment: Bresenham is a line algorithm and you can probably use it to trace your contour so you don't end up with a vertex on each pixel. Delaunay triangulation can be used to get triangles out of your vertices so you don't end up with convex polygons.

Comment: I've tried to do something like here https://hastebin.com/ruyodevapi.java But it's still dont't working how should I fix it? When I call Polygon.area() the result is 0.